# Wrong value of Mon when retrieve from POSIXlt of current time

Tags: r, posixlt

The value of "mon" which is month of the year returned is 7 instead of 8. What is the possible cause of this? I am using RStudio - Version 0.99.467.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images.  You had to add 1 to POSIXlt `mon` output as it starts with 0

Comment: ...as clearly documented at `?POSIXlt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIXlt](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html)

mon
0–11: months after the first of the year.

Comment: Could you expand your answer? For the moment, you don't give more information than the above comments.

Comment: If you wrapped it in a full example it would probably be good for the OP. Otherwise, this provides no additional value than the comments do.

Comment: From the document, the value of the month is from 0~11. So the value of August will be 7 instead of 8.